# Is there any need for mysqlnd if im only writing PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

Is there any need for mysqlnd if im only writing PDO? Im aking because i have been stressing myself out dealing with my host provider trying to get mysqlnd to work. is it easier to just  to write pdo instead of procedural php?

Comment: check phpinfo pdo.

Comment: i have checked the phpinfo.  i called them because it says that mysqlnd is enabled but my mysql_stmt_get_result is still coming back undefined function. i have tried to configure a php5.ini file to work with mysql and mysqli but no luck as of yet.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_get_result, not is mysql_stmt_get_result. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: i know how to write the statement. again the problem is that mysqlnd is enabled but the function is still being returned as undefined.